# How to prevent two for more components to overlap each other when resizing window?

Tags: c++, resize, vcl

I'm currently developing on GUI application in RAD Studio XE.
In the form I've created two panels `Panel1 and Panel2`. And each panel has two GroupBoxs `GroupBox1` and `GroupBox2` for Panel1 and `GroupBox3` and `GroupBox4` for Panel2 and each GroupBox has GridPanel `GridPanel1` for GroupBox1, `GridPanel2` for GroupBox2, `GridPanel3` for GroupBox3, `GridPanel4` for GroupBox4 within it with `3 Rows and 2 Columns` having labels in each row and column.

Now when I run the application and resize the window to minimum all the `contents overlap each other`.

So what I want is that whenever I minimize the window all the content should be displayed without getting overlapped.

This is how my form looks like: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiw5X.jpg)

Comment: There were `MinimalWidth` and `MinimalHeight` properties, as I recall.

Answer (score -1):

There is a property `Align` of controls for that purpose. It works as follows:

In order to divide the client area of a form in two parts    horizontally, put Panel1 with `Align=alClient` and Panel2 with    `Align=alRight`. If you drag the right border of a form, Panel1 keeps the    same width, Panel2 re sizes.

If you would like to let user move a border between them, put a `TSplitter` component. Also set constraints on minimal width of a form, so that the user cannot make a form so narrow, that the `TSplitter` runs out of view.

In a case of 4 panels I would suggest at first split form vertically with 2 panels: `PanelTop (alClient)` and `PanelBottom (alBottom)`, then put Panel1, 2 on PanelTop, 3,4 - on `PanelBottom`, splitting them horizontally.

**Note**, that the vertical splitters in top and bottom panel will move independently. If you want them to stay synchronized, or if you want your panels to divide client area always into equal parts, or any other behavior, you need just write a handler on the OnResize event of the form. Analyse the current size of client area and manually set the sizes and positions of panels as you like (you may need not splitters in this case).

Comment: Please add some formatting to your answer. Currently, it is really hard (or almost impossible) to follow it, while some improvements might actually make it a good answer.